# Hibernate attempts to remove previously deleted row

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

There is a table A with the following columns

```
id bigint NOT NULL,
b_id bigint
 CONSTRAINT fk1b51366dc7a1b06c FOREIGN KEY (b_id)
      REFERENCES B (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Now I have an object objectB that has a field referencing a value from table A

```
@OneToOne(fetch = EAGER, cascade = PERSIST, mappedBy = "b")
private A a;
```

I try to remove first from database the value from table A associated with the objectB.

```
    if (objectB.getA() != null) {
        aRepository.remove(objectB.getA());
    }
    objectB.setA(null);
```

and then remove objectB

```
bRepository.remove(objectB);
```

The error comes when trying to remove objectB as it seems that Hibernate wants still to delete the row from table A that was previously removed already and I get this exception:

```
javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

What is the solution for this? Why does Hibernate want to delete the value from table A even if the reference to A from objectB is set to null? If I don't remove first the associated value from table A then I get an exception that the value of objectB.id is still referenced in the table A.

Comment: What I am thinking is that here is XY problem. You as for a remedy to the particular cause of the desiese, while the real cause is different then you assume.

Comment: *mappedBy = "student"* and now we know your secrets.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a bidirectional association , and then set cascade type to remove:

```
//define this association in A
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, optional=true)
    private B b;
```

an then removing like this would do the trick:

```
bRepository.remove(objectA.getB());
```